# How to create a 3 dimensional array and then pull info 1 dimension at a time?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I would like to take data sets from Sheet 1 and fill in table values in Sheet 2. I believe using a multidimensional array to be the optimum way of accomplishing this.

Sheet 1 is setup as such:
Column A = "Dates", Column C = "SNs", Column E = "M0s", and Column F = "HNs".

An operator enters in an M0 value, and if a ("E").Row has that value, I want that row's SN, HN, and Date to be entered into Sheet 2. Just because two rows have the same M0 doesn't mean they have the same SN, HN, or Date. I would like each row's values to be stored separately, hence a multidimensional array (3 dimensional in this case).

The code below is my successful attempt at storing all SNs in an single dimensional array (based on M0 entered) and then entering those values into Sheet 2.

```
        Sub FillSheet2()
        Dim varSNarray As Variant
        Dim M0cell As Range
        Dim SNcell As Long  'could be substituted with Variant or String

        ReDim varSNarray(0)
        For Each M0cell In ws.Range("E7:E200000").Cells
            If M0cell.Value <> vbNullString Then
                If M0cell.Value = varPrintM0 Then
                    SNcell = ws.Range("C" & M0cell.Row).Value
                    varSNarray(UBound(varSNarray)) = SNcell
                    ReDim Preserve varSNarray(UBound(varSNarray) + 1) As Variant

                End If
            End If
        Next M0cell

        ReDim Preserve varSNarray(UBound(varSNarray) - 1)

        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(varSNarray) To UBound(varSNarray)

            Dim ws2range As Range
            Dim ws2SNcellnum As Long

            If i > 149 Then
                Set ws2range = ws2.Range("AN6:AN55")
                    ws2SNcellnum = i - 144
                    ws2.Range("AN" & ws2SNcellnum).Value = varSNarray(i)

            ElseIf i > 99 Then
                Set ws2range = ws2.Range("AA6:AA55")
                    ws2SNcellnum = i - 94
                    ws2.Range("AA" & ws2SNcellnum).Value = varSNarray(i)

            ElseIf i > 49 Then
                Set ws2range = ws2.Range("N6:N55")
                    ws2SNcellnum = i - 44
                    ws2.Range("N" & ws2SNcellnum).Value = varSNarray(i)

            Else
                Set ws2range = ws2.Range("A6:A55")
                    ws2SNcellnum = i + 6
                    ws2.Range("A" & ws2SNcellnum).Value = varSNarray(i)
            End If


        Next i
 End Sub
```

I would like to add HN and Date along with SN as this sub runs. I don't know how to augment the array to allow for HN and Date storage though. Below is how I imagine it would look like. However, I cannot successfully create my array. I'm fairly sure it has something to do with my variable setups.

```
            Dim varSNarray As Variant
            Dim M0cell As Range
            Dim SNcell As Long
            Dim HNcell As Long
            Dim Datecell As Long

            ReDim varSNarray(0, 0, 0)
            For Each M0cell In ws.Range("E7:E200000").Cells
                If M0cell.Value <> vbNullString Then
                    If M0cell.Value = varPrintM0 Then
                    SNcell = ws.Range("C" & M0cell.Row).Value
                        varSNarray(UBound(varSNarray), HNcell, Datecell) = SNcell
                        varSNarray(SNcell, UBound(varSNarray), Datecell) = HNcell 'Script out of range error
                        varSNarray(SNcell, HNcell, UBound(varSNarray)) = Datecell

                        ReDim Preserve varSNarray(UBound(varSNarray) + 1, UBound(varSNarray) + 1, UBound(varSNarray) + 1) As Variant

                    End If


                End If
            Next M0cell

            ReDim Preserve varSNarray(UBound(varSNarray) - 1)

            Dim i As Long
            For i = LBound(varSNarray) To UBound(varSNarray)

                Dim ws2range As Range
                Dim ws2SNcellnum As Long

                If i > 149 Then
                    Set ws2range = ws2.Range("AN6:AN55")
                        ws2SNcellnum = i - 144
                        ws2.Range("AN" & ws2SNcellnum).Value = varSNarray(i)
                        ws2.Range("AN" & ws2SNcellnum).Value = varSNarray(HNcell)
                        ws2.Range("AN" & ws2SNcellnum).Value = varSNarray(Datecell)
                 ''''  
                 Removed this section has its the same as above
                 ''''
                    Set ws2range = ws2.Range("A6:A55")
                        ws2SNcellnum = i + 6
                        ws2.Range("A" & ws2SNcellnum).Value = varSNarray(i)
                        ws2.Range("A" & ws2SNcellnum).Value = varSNarray(HNcell)
                        ws2.Range("A" & ws2SNcellnum).Value = varSNarray(Datecell)

                End If


            Next i
```

How do I store data into a 3 dimensional array and then successful pull 1 dimension from the array at a time?

Comment: 1) "Just because two rows have the same M0 doesn't mean they have the same SN, HN, or Date." - so the `M0` are not unique identifiers? Then you're going to be running into plenty of problems.

Comment: 2) I see no reason to use a multidimensional array for this example. An unnecessary complication. I'd just use three separate arrays for the values of `Dates`, `SNs` and `HNs`.

Comment: 3) It would work much faster if you actually read the values of all `M0s` into an array too and do everything 'in memory' rather than reading data from the `Sheet1`.

Comment: It looks to me like you are simply scanning down column C on Sheet 1 for a particular MO value and copying the SN value to sheet 2. The first 50 records in Col A (1), next 50 col N (14), next 50 col AA (27) and the rest to col AN (40). Do you want the other values along side eg HN in Col B,O,AB,AO and Date in Col C,P,AC,AP ?

Comment: For example, I have 50 different SNs which have the same M0 value, but 2 different HNs and 3 different Dates in Sheet1. Each SN receives its own row. I would like all SNs that have the same M0 (50 in this example) and then log each one into Sheet2 along with its respective HN, Date, and M0. I'm moving all these values to Sheet2 because I would like to print from there instead of Sheet1 (because of formatting concerns).

Comment: M0 isn't a unique identifier per say. Sheet1 will eventually have hundreds of different M0s, each with sequential SNs.  For example, SNs 1-5 belong to M0 1. SNs 6-10 belong to M02, and so on. I believe using M0 number is the most efficient method of finding all serial numbers belonging to said M0. The HN and Date are tag along data - each unique to a SN (even though most SNs share HN and Date, but unfortunately not all). I will try Danny's idea of using 3 arrays instead of overcomplicating things.

Comment: OK, I understand the relationship 1 MO has many SN's, each SN can have many records. Reading your code, where there are 50 records with that MO these will be copied to Col A rows 5 to 54 on sheet2. If there are 60 the next 10 will fill Col N row 5 to 14 and so on. Do you want the other data alongside so NH is in col B, Date in col C ? If there are eventually more MO's on the sheet will the next block of records start at row 56 for example ?

Comment: Not exactly. Only SNs (along with their individual HNs and Dates) belonging to one M0 value can fill Sheet2 at a time. This is so information pertaining to that single M0 value is printed at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think an array is necessary here, just write the records to Sheet 2 as they are found. For example

```
Option Explicit
Sub FillSheet2()

    Const COL_DATE = "A"
    Const COL_SN = "C"
    Const COL_M0 = "E"
    Const COL_HN = "F"
    Const START_ROW = 7

    ' target sheet
    Const TARGET_START_ROW = 5
    Const TARGET_START_COL = 1 'A
    Const COL_REPEAT = 13 ' N, AA, AN
    Const MAX_ROWS = 50

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsTarget = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    wsTarget.Cells.Clear

    Dim iRow As Integer, iLastRow As Integer, iCount As Integer
    Dim iTargetRow As Integer, iTargetCol As Integer, sM0 As String
    Dim varPrintM0 As String

    iTargetCol = TARGET_START_COL
    iTargetRow = TARGET_START_ROW

    varPrintM0 = "Test4"

    iCount = 0
    iLastRow = wsSource.Range(COL_M0 & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' ----------    
    With wsSource
        For iRow = START_ROW To iLastRow
            sM0 = .Range(COL_M0 & iRow)
            If sM0 = varPrintM0 Then

                With wsTarget.Cells(iTargetRow, iTargetCol)
                  .Offset(0, 0) = wsSource.Range(COL_SN & iRow).Value
                  .Offset(0, 1) = wsSource.Range(COL_HN & iRow).Value
                  .Offset(0, 2) = wsSource.Range(COL_DATE & iRow).Value
                End With
                iTargetRow = iTargetRow + 1

                If iTargetRow >= MAX_ROWS + TARGET_START_ROW Then
                  iTargetCol = iTargetCol + COL_REPEAT
                  iTargetRow = TARGET_START_ROW
                End If
                iCount = iCount + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox iCount & " rows copied", vbInformation, "Finished"        
    ' --------

End Sub
```

If you do want to use an array replace the code between the ------ lines above with this

```
    Dim ar(5, 50, 3) As Variant ' max of 5 blocks of 50 records
    Dim t As Integer, r As Long
    t = 1: r = 1

    ' fill array
    With wsSource
        For iRow = START_ROW To iLastRow
            sM0 = .Range(COL_M0 & iRow)
            If sM0 = varPrintM0 Then

                With wsTarget.Cells(iTargetRow, iTargetCol)
                    ar(t, r, 0) = sM0
                    ar(t, r, 1) = wsSource.Range(COL_SN & iRow).Value
                    ar(t, r, 2) = wsSource.Range(COL_HN & iRow).Value
                    ar(t, r, 3) = wsSource.Range(COL_DATE & iRow).Value
                End With

                r = r + 1
                If r > MAX_ROWS Then
                    r = 1
                    t = t + 1
                End If
                iCount = iCount + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With

    ' output array
    Dim iLastTable As Long, c As Long
    iLastTable = t
    For t = 1 To iLastTable
        For r = 1 To 50
            c = 1 + COL_REPEAT * (t - 1)
            With wsTarget.Cells(r + 4, c)
                .Offset(0, 0) = ar(t, r, 1)
                .Offset(0, 1) = ar(t, r, 2)
                .Offset(0, 2) = ar(t, r, 3)
            End With
        Next r
    Next t
    MsgBox iCount & " rows copied using Array", vbInformation, "Finished"
```

Comment: How would you find the maximum value within the multidimensional array?

Is there a way to do UBound(ar(t, r, 1)) ?    Essentially finding the min and max SN being added to the array.

Comment: @r z The array size if fixed at (5,50,3) so Ubound is not relevant. It the SN numbers are sorted then you could use the first and last elements. min would be ar(1,1,1) and max ar(t,r,1) on exit from loop. If not sorted either scan the whole array or calc min and max when you scan sheet 1.